# mean stack route not returning a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to create a controller /projects that returns all of the data in the collection 'work'.  The data is there and the call completes as a 200 but just returns [], or test:test if uncommented.  Can someone point me in the right direction, I'm new to the MEAN stack.

server/controllers/work.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Work = mongoose.model('Work');

exports.all = function(req, res) {

  Work
    .find()
    .exec(function(err, project) {
      console.log(project);
      res.json(project);
      //res.json({"test":"test"});
    });

};
```

public/system/controllers/work.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.system').controller('WorkController', ['$scope', 'Global', '$http',     
function ($scope, Global, $http) {

  $scope.global = Global;

  $http.get('/projects').success(function(d) {

  }).error(function(d) {

  });

}]);
```

server/routes/work.js

```
'use strict';

// User routes use users controller
var work = require('../controllers/work');

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/projects', work.all);

};
```

Comment: are you sure you have data. open your mongo cli and have a look. `mongo <dbname>` then `db.works.find()` (if you are unsure of collection name do `show collections;` to get a list of collections

Comment: yeah there is data when I access the collection in the mongo shell in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, for some reason the collection was being named 'works' instead of 'work' somewhere.  Maybe this is done automatically in mongoose or something but it fixed the issue.

Comment: express tries to pluralize collection names based on document name. For example 'article' becomes 'articles' etc etc. When you use `mongoose.model('ModelName')` it should still understand what you are asking for. I am curious to see your model to try understand why you see such behaviour.